# S3FileTransformOperator Permission Denied Error in Cloud Composer On a Script

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to use the S3FileTransformOperator with a file `transform.sh` but I keep hitting a Permission Denied error, more specifically `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/airflow/gcs/plugins/some_plugin/scripts/transform.sh'`
This seems to work both locally and in my self managed Airflow environment but I cant seem to get this to work on Cloud Composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an AWS reference but can you try if possible changing the permission of the file using the chmod command? The article refers to the same error as you posted.

> chmod 777 transform_test.sh

Reference:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/t-apache-airflow-202.html#op-s3-transform